# Django : user.is_authenticated, works without passing 'user'?

Tags: django, django-templates

While I was following a tutorial, I came across this: 
I have a template,'base.html' in which I didn't even pass the value for 'user' variable from a view.
But still it authenticates the user. I can't understand how this works:

base.html :

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}

<div id='nav'>
    <a href='/'/> mysite </a> |
    <a href='/user/{{user.username}}/'>{{ user.username }} </a>(<a href='/logout'>logout</a>)
</div>

{% endif %}
<h1>{% block head %}{% endblock %}</h1>
{% block content %}{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access to the `user` object even if you don't pass it implicitly in the view response. 
By default it is an `anonymous user`, until an user log in and authenticates itself

Answer (score 0):

You probably have the auth context processor and/or middleware set which adds the user variable to context

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    "django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware",
)
```

Comment: The middleware has nothing to do with this.

Comment: @hedde Nope,I don't have the context processor set. No clue about where the template is getting 'user'value from.